# Input type-search not redirecting

Tags: search, text, input, field, box

I wanted to make a regular search box, just styled differently (I didn't use a regular "submit" button, but replaced it with an image). Apparently, when I type something in the box, and click the image/submit button/, it's not reacting.

```
<form action="http://search.com">
           <input type="text" name="Search bar" placeholder="Search..."/>
           <input type="search" name="Search"
          value="submit" />

           </form>
```

The style.css:

```
input[type=search] {padding:5px 15px; 

border:1px solid #FF0;
cursor:pointer;
text-color:#FFF;
background:url(../gl-11.png);
border:0;

height:24px;
width: 24px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

I might have messed up something in the code!

[This is how the search box looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXSb4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of button to submit. [A simple guide.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

```
<form action="http://search.com">
    <input type="text" name="Search bar" placeholder="Search..."/>
    <input type="submit" name="Search" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is a regular form button, not submit.To be a submit button its type should be "submit". You can apply style using css classes.

```
<form action="http://search.com">
       <input type="text" name="Search bar" placeholder="Search..."/>
       <input type="submit" class="MySearchButton" name="Search"
      value="submit" />

       </form>


input.MySearchButton {padding:5px 15px; 
....
```